# Remote Blob Storage - Installation help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, remote-blob-storage

My DBA has configured our SharePoint SQL instance for file streaming, and verified all of the settings are correct. I have been following Todd Klindts post on configuring RBS, and everything seems fine until i get to enabling RBS.

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=174

The RBS client was downloaded from the Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2 feature pack site http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

The install command for the RBS client

```
msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log.txt /i RBS.msi TRUSTSERVERCERTIFICATE=true      
FILEGROUP=PRIMARY DBNAME=”WSS_Content_Blob” DBINSTANCE=”9904\sharepoint”  
FILESTREAMFILEGROUP=RBSFilestreamProvider FILESTREAMSTORENAME=FilestreamProvider
```

The command to enable RBS

```
PS C:\Users\white2> $cdb = Get-SPContentDatabase wss_content_blob
PS C:\Users\white2> $rbss = $cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
PS C:\Users\white2> $rbss.Installed()
False
PS C:\Users\white2> $rbss.Enable()
Exception calling "Enable" with "0" argument(s): "SQL remote blob storage must
be installed on each web front end server and on the content database before it
may be used."
At line:1 char:13
+ $rbss.Enable <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any help would be great

thanks,
Jason

Comment: Did you install the RBS.msi on all SharePoint servers in the farm?

Comment: there is only one SharePoint server in the farm. The SQL server is on a different VM

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The architecture is one stand-alone server, but I receive exactly the same error :-( How can I solve it, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that running the msiexec via command prompt didn't work. I double clicked on it and ran through the wizard, worked great after that!

Comment: Running the wizard did help resolve our original issue. However we did experience a new set of issues when adding additional servers. The cause was a set of group policies changing various settings on the servers themselves. Due to group policies being enforced out of our control, we had to abandon using RBS.

Answer (score 0):

If you experienced this problem check:

- all SQL servers in farm have installed latest SQL Server service pack
- run rbs.msi through administrator command line without parameters and install by GUI
- restart server where you run $rbs.Enable()